# how to prevent python from stopping the code after one integer value is read?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am making a project where an arduino sends a "1" (49) or "2" (50) based on wether the door of a room is open or closed. There is then a python program that then switches the windows open on the computer. The arduino is running fine but the python project doesent work properly. Here is the code:

```
import pyautogui as pa
import serial
#import time

ser = serial.Serial("COM4", 9600)

data_raw = ser.read()
int_val = int.from_bytes(data_raw, "big")
print(int_val)

if (int_val == 49):
    pa.hotkey('win','d') #will switch one desktop to the left

if (int_val == 50):
    pa.hotkey('alt','tab') #will switch one desktop to the left
```

The code can print the correct number sent by the arduino but doesent perform the correct hotkey press. Only the first number sent is read and applied. The code then stops immediatly with the following message:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "data_raw" is probably a byte sequence of length 1, e. g. `b'1'` and not a number.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for your reply. After converting the bytes value to integer the system works but there is another problem now. The code just stops running after the first value is read. It just prints: Process finished with exit code 0. I will edit the question or just create a new one but any help is appreciated.

Comment: well if it prints 49 if you send '1' the problem must be in the `pa.hotkey('win','d')`

Comment: To repeat something indefinitely move it into a `while True:` block.

Comment: @Piglet Hi that is not the problem. That is because of bytes-integer interfaceing. 49 in int variable is 1 in bytes variable.

Comment: @MichaelButscher thank you for the answer. Everything works now. Highly appreciated.